# jqPlot: Can a cut-out slice of a pie contain slices?

Tags: jqplot, pie-chart

I have this Jqplot pie chart with some cut-out slices:

```
var data = [['SliceOfSlices', 60],['a', 10],['b', 5],['c', 25],['d', 10],];

plot = $.jqplot('pie-graph', [data], {
    title: 'Slices',
    seriesDefaults: {
        renderer: $.jqplot.PieRenderer,
        rendererOptions: {
            sliceMargin: 8,
        }
    }
});
```

JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/b4bu/h5TEZ/3/).

What I'd like to do is to let one of the slices contain slices of its own, without cutting them up. Like so:
[image: Pie with slice of slices]

I've looked around and I suspect this might be stretching the capabilities of the jqplot library a bit far... Just thought I'd ask.